# SQL query for three small tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anything wrong with my SQL query that anyone can see? I'm working with three tables called SHPMT, ORIGIN, and SHPMT_TRUCK and the expected output should be Location, Ship_Day, Count_With_Truck and Count_Without_Truck. Please let me know if additional information is needed. Thanks!

```
SELECT 
  SHPMT.Origin_Abbr AS Location, 
  DATE(SHPMT.Sched_Tsp) AS Ship_Day,
  COUNT(SHPMT_TRUCK.Truck_ID) AS Count_With_Truck,
  (COUNT(SHPMT.ID) - COUNT(TRUCK.TRUCK_ID)) AS Count_Without_Truck,
FROM SHPMT
WHERE ORIGIN.Typ_Cd = 'BRWY'
  AND SHPMT.Shp_Tsp = NULL
  AND Count_With_Truck > Count_Without_Truck
JOIN SHPMT_TRUCK ON SHPMT.ID = SHPMT_TRUCK.Shpmt_ID 
JOIN ORIGIN ON SHPMT.Origin_Abbr = ORIGIN.Origin_Abbr
GROUP BY SHPMT.Origin_Abbr, DATE(SHPMT.Sched_Tsp)
ORDER BY SHPMT.Origin_Abbr, COUNT(SHPMT.Shpmt_ID);
```

Comment: Not that familiar with MySQL but shouldn't your joins be BEFORE the Where Clause?

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: Equal null should be IS NULL and what @B.Seberle said.

Comment: joins are after the from then where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know where to begin :)

- As @B. Seberle said in his comment JOIN should be before the WHERE
  clause
- In one place you use `TRUCK.TRUCK_ID` where TRUCK should be an alias of a `SHPMT_TRUCK` table but you have not given that alias to
  that table like this: `JOIN SHPMT_TRUCK TRUCK ON SHPMT.ID = TRUCK.Shpmt_ID`. And then of course you should change every reference
  to the columns from the SHPMT_TRUCK tables
- You have used aliases in query that are created in the query : `Count_Without_Truck` and `Count_With_Truck`
- It is `IS NULL` and not `= NULL`
- `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are not ok....

Well when I remove all this errors and some more then I get this:

```
select * from (SELECT SHPMT.Origin_Abbr AS Location
       , DATE(SHPMT.Sched_Tsp) AS Ship_Day
       , COUNT(TRUCK.Truck_ID) AS Count_With_Truck
       , (COUNT(SHPMT.ID) - COUNT(TRUCK.TRUCK_ID)) AS Count_Without_Truck
FROM SHPMT
JOIN SHPMT_TRUCK TRUCK ON SHPMT.ID = TRUCK.Shpmt_ID
JOIN ORIGIN ON SHPMT.Origin_Abbr = ORIGIN.Origin_Abbr
WHERE ORIGIN.Typ_Cd = 'BRWY'
AND SHPMT.Shp_Tsp IS NULL
GROUP BY SHPMT.Origin_Abbr, SHPMT.Sched_Tsp
ORDER BY SHPMT.Origin_Abbr, SHPMT.Sched_Tsp) A
where Count_With_Truck > Count_Without_Truck;
```

Or you can do it with HAVING as @scaisEdge advised(Thanks @scaisEdge!):

```
SELECT SHPMT.Origin_Abbr AS Location
       , DATE(SHPMT.Sched_Tsp) AS Ship_Day
       , COUNT(TRUCK.Truck_ID) AS Count_With_Truck
       , (COUNT(SHPMT.ID) - COUNT(TRUCK.TRUCK_ID)) AS Count_Without_Truck
FROM SHPMT
JOIN SHPMT_TRUCK TRUCK ON SHPMT.ID = TRUCK.Shpmt_ID
JOIN ORIGIN ON SHPMT.Origin_Abbr = ORIGIN.Origin_Abbr
WHERE ORIGIN.Typ_Cd = 'BRWY'
AND SHPMT.Shp_Tsp IS NULL
GROUP BY SHPMT.Origin_Abbr, SHPMT.Sched_Tsp
having COUNT(TRUCK.Truck_ID) > (COUNT(SHPMT.ID) - COUNT(TRUCK.TRUCK_ID))
ORDER BY SHPMT.Origin_Abbr, SHPMT.Sched_Tsp;
```

But I can not be sure if this will get you the data you need.
Here is the simple [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ed389f86997537ffb72e742eb98c91a)

Comment: the last where  ..  could be an having ???  two where cluase seems weird to me

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, I agree, I have added that proposition to my answer and in the DEMO. Cheers!

Comment: The two wheres will not work.

Comment: Hi @Hogan, please can you tell me why. This is a simple test example here(check the new link in this comment) i know but please do elaborate your "will not work". It is always welcome. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=191b0a5ab663263f3c3cac02221f265b

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help and also for not being mean– I'm brand new to SQL. Have a good one!

Comment: Hi @Kee, you are welcome, also if this answer helped you please do mark it as coreect. If you do not know how do tell. P.S. good luck with learning.

Comment: @VBokšić -- Looks like this is just one more way MySQL is different than **every** other sql platform.  They will all give you an error if you have two wheres.  In those cases you have to use the HAVING keyword.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand, so you say this fiddle(my demo example) is not realistic ? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @VBokšić -- MySQL is different than all other SQL implementations.  so it is realistic -- just not standard.

Comment: I understand that it is not standard. But I am still troubled with : why will there be an error when in my demo example (demo is simulating mysql) all is ok and it is working without error (the one with two where clause)

Answer (score 0):

You need IS NULL IN WHERE clause not `=` and here join should be used before where as your referenced tables should be present first to be able to use in where to filter

```
   WHERE ORIGIN.Typ_Cd = 'BRWY'
   AND SHPMT.Shp_Tsp IS NULL
```